# instance field native JS global

Tags: javascript, gwt, field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 0;
</script>
```

Now I have GWT:

```
public class AA implements EntryPoint {

  public final int a =44;

}
```

How can i transfer instance field a to native global javascript variable so that it can be callable from javascript method?

Comment: http://www.emgarten.com/using-jsni-in-gwt.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public native void init ( Integer arg )/*-{
    $wnd.a = arg;
}-*/;
```